# Error installing TensorFlow GPU in Google Colab: subprocess-exited-with-error

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu, google-colaboratory

At first I choose the runtime to be GPU and selected the available T4 GPU. Then I try to install TensorFlow GPU in Google Colab by running the command !pip install tensorflow-gpu

```
!pip install tensorflow-gpu
```

But I encountered this error:

```
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://us-python.pkg.dev/colab- 
wheels/public/simple/
Collecting tensorflow-gpu
Using cached tensorflow-gpu-2.12.0.tar.gz (2.6 kB)
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

I have already tried upgrading pip, clearing the pip cache, and restarting the Colab runtime, but the issue persists. I suspect there might be compatibility or network-related problems. Can someone help me understand the cause of this error and suggest possible solutions to resolve it? Are there any specific steps I should take or alternative installation approaches I can try to successfully install TensorFlow GPU in Google Colab?

Thank you in advance for any assistance or insights you can provide.

Comment: "note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip." I believe its a problem with the notebook, not with. Pip. Have you tried in another notebook-platform??

Comment: No I tried it on the google colab only. Can u suggest some other platform where I can try?

Comment: Did you find any solution? I am also getting same error.

Answer (score 0):

Google Colab has by-default the latest stable tensorflow and python version installed. You need not to install the tensorflow-gpu to have GPU support enabled in Google Colab untill you need a specific tensorflow version required for your code. You can access the tensorflow package with gpu enabled directly by importing the tensorflow and setting the runtime to GPU as below.

[image]

You can follow the below steps to install and access the specific tensorflow version(suppose 2.10) with gpu support in Google Colab:

```
!pip install tensorflow==2.10   #restart the kernel
import tensorflow as tf
tf.__version__         # '2.10.0'

#to check, if GPU enabled
tf.config.list_physical_devices() 
# Output - [PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:CPU:0', device_type='CPU')]

#if no GPU device shows up, change the Colab runtime to GPU mode and re-run the same code

tf.config.list_physical_devices() 
#Output - [PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:CPU:0', device_type='CPU'),
#          PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
```